# Block cut with sed and suppress the last line

Tags: bash, sed

```
# cat file 
LBL 434
any lines but not block start
...
LBL 75677
...
any
LBL 777
...
LBL 798
...

# sed -ne '/LBL 75677/,/LBL/p' file | head -n -1
LBL 75677
...
any
#
```

The above command is good for me, but I would like to know:
Can I suppress the last line without the head command, only in one sed script? I know the commands and control flow of sed (N P D b ...) but I couldn't figure out it at the moment.

@Cyrus, Thanks It works fine and I know how it  works thanks again.
But I wanted to find different way of solution if it is.
I tried the lines of block `/LBL 75677/,/LBL/` put into the space buffer of sed with `N` command and `D` remove the last line from space buffer (this is first line of new block) and print all space buffer. Does somebody can do it.

Comment: `sed -ne '/LBL 75677/,/LBL/{ /LBL/{/LBL 75677/!d};p}' file`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below script :

```
sed -n '/LBL 75677/{p;:loop;n;/LBL/!{p;b loop}}' file
```

may be what you're looking for.

`:loop` here is a label and `b loop` is unconditional jumping to that label.

Here we create a small loop and go on to print the lines until the next **LBL** is reached.

Comment: Thank you this very good, but do you think is there an other way with space buffer pls. see end of my modified question.

Comment: @LászlóSzilágyi You may not use the `N` option here  because you use **LBL** as a  delimiter here. Also the `D` command deletes the first portion of the pattern space, up to the new line character which is not desirable here

Answer (score 2):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines (`s/old/new/`), that is all. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk '/LBL/{f=0} /LBL 75677/{f=1} f' file
LBL 75677
...
any
```

In addition to being simpler and clearer than an equivalent sed script, the above will execute faster (especially if you only want one record output and so can change `/LBL/{f=0}` to `/LBL/{exit}`), and be more portable as it will work as-is on all awks on all UNIX systems and will be vastly easier to enhance if/when your requirements change (when dealing with anything more than `s/old/new/` a tiny requirements change typically means a complete rewrite for a sed script).

If you're using any constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) in sed then you are using constructs that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented and so sed no longer needed all the cryptic runes to perform simple multi-line tasks.

Comment: I know and I agree with these but sometimes I like to
create sed scripts as brain teaser.

Comment: You should state in your question when the solution **must** be with one specific tool as usually when someone asks for or tags a question with sed or some other UNIX tool it's just because that's their best guess at the tool they'll need and in reality they're happy with whichever UNIX tool that best solves the problem.